# Why do you need to substract initial investment in NPV formula?

Tags: finance, economics

The initial cash flow(s) of a project will be negative because of the investment.

Why do you need to substract the initial investment in order to calculate **NPV**?

Doesnt't the initial investment already cancel out with the other positive cash flows? By substracting the initial investment, doesn't it basically mean that you want to recover at least 2 times the initial investment?

Can you please shed some light on this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

NPV measures the *net* present value of the investment, that is, the value of the investment *minus the initial outlay*. Therefore $0$ is meaningful, as an investment that breaks even under the discounting assumptions.